# Comprar si un numero es divisible sin usar el operador %

Tags: java

tengo que crear un programa con las siguientes caracteristicas:

Crear un metodo que genere un numero aleatorio entero positivo y devuelva una cadena que
diga si es divisible para 3 o para 6 o para ambos o para ninguno.
Nota: No se puede utilizar el operador % para calcular la divisibilidad.

tengo todo el codigo listo, pero el problema es que al momento de comprobar si uno de esos numeros aleatorios es divisor de 3 o 6, no logro manera de comprobarlo sin usar el operador %.

Comment: Lee por favor [ask]

Comment: Falta un [mre]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conviértelos a double y haz la división. Resta al resultado la parte entera de sí mismo y si hay un sobrante entonces no es divisible.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int val1 = 45;
        int val2 = 46;
        System.out.println("Numero 45 es divisible por 3: " + test(val1, 3));
        System.out.println("Numero 46 es divisible por 3: " + test(val2, 3));
    }
    
    public static boolean test(Integer dividendo, Integer divisor) {
        Double result = dividendo.doubleValue() / divisor;
        return result - result.intValue() == 0;
    }
```

El código imprimiría esto:

```
Numero 45 es divisible por 3: true
Numero 46 es divisible por 3: false
```

Answer (score 0):

De momento lo unico que se me ocurre es que en un for hagas la multiplicacion sea <= a el numero a consultar

ejemplo :

```
    int numeroLimite = 10;// Este numero lo estableces segun lo requieras
    /*
     * multiploTres = 3 ; con esta variables vas multiplicando hasta igualar
     * y/o pasar el numero que quieres comprobar 
     * 
     * tambien podrias añadir la variable multiploSeis = 6 al for y calcular si es multiplo de 3 y 6
     * al mismo tiempo 
    */
    int multiploTres = 3;               
    for (int i = 0; i <= numeroLimite; i++) {
        multiploTres = 3*i;
        if(multiploTres>numeroLimite) {
            System.out.println("El numero "+numeroLimite+" No es multiplo de 3");
            break;
        }
        if(multiploTres == numeroLimite) {
            System.out.println("El numero "+numeroLimite+" es multiplo de 3");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero tu respuesta dista mucho de ser una solución al problema. Te invito a leer [answer]. La pregunta es deficiente, evita responder preguntas de este estilo ya que terminan cerradas y tu aporte se pierde. Saludos